# Is there a free android app which can launch apps on a successful wifi connection?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, launcher

Is there a free android aplication which can launch other pre-selected apps when it detects a successful wifi connection?

Bonus, if it can kill the apps when the wifi connection is gone.

I know plug in launcher pro version claims that it has this feature (but it ain't free)

More background:

I'm using wifi powermanager to startup wifi whenever a power source is connected. Once wifi, is connected, I wish to start applications like airdroid, wifi fixer.

Answer (score 4):

Try [AutomateIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage).  This app allows you to set up various triggers (WiFi enabled/disabled included) and then assign actions like launching apps or toggling other settings.

Comment: You can take a look at the following link for a detailed user guide of AutomateIt: http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/automateit-automate-your-android.html

Answer (score 2):

The free [Llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) app allows you to combine rules (when connected to certain wlan) with action (then launch this app).